# What is most efficient way to automatically scrape new news articles from news sources?

Tags: screen-scraping

I want to build a news aggregator application. I have one problem that I don't know how should I take new news articles from news webpages.
I wrote a scraper script in python in which when I run it takes all the news from the source (published today the time of running) and saves them in to a CSV file (I save: URL, Title, Date, Time, Image URL, Category, Content). When I run the script again it checks with the CSV file if it processed the URLs so it does not write duplicate content, only writes the new content. And at the end I want to write these results to my database.
But with this script I have to run it periodically to (lets say every 10 mins) to check if there is new content published.
Is this the write way to accomplish this?
Is there a better way to listen to news sources which can take when the new content is published?
If this is the way to do it how can I set the script to run periodically?
Greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

> I run the script again it checks with the CSV file if it processed the URLs so it does not write duplicate content, only writes the new content.

You might add to your question:

- website address
- python code that you've already done

My suggestion for you: Get the most recent URLs from DB (say 100-200, number should be comparable with URLs number on the web page to scrape) and check them against the present URLs on the web page. If new URLs appear, do scrape them.